# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'system.collections.generic.list

Tags: c#

I struggle with a procedural proggramming exercise.  I have to call the method, but when i hover above Consecutive(input) it says:

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'system.collections.generic.list.

I don't know how to bypass this because i frankly don't know how to convert the string to system.collections.generic.list . This is the code i use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a few numbers (eg 1-2-3-4): ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Consecutive(input));
        }

        public static bool Consecutive(List<int> input)
        {
            var numbers = new int[input.Count];
            input.CopyTo(numbers);
            Array.Sort(numbers);
            for (var i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] != numbers[i - 1] + 1)
                    return false;
            }
           return true;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: you need to parse input to list ... try split by '-' then use parse from int class

Comment: like `input.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToList()` using LINQ

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I realize now it isn't really relevant to the topic but it's my first time with the term. I was doing this excersise in udemy that was titled like that.

Comment: In general, when you are accepting input from users, you should expect that the input will often be wrong.  If you parse your integers with `int.Parse`, it will throw an exception if the string you are parsing is not an integer (and, user input error is hardly an *exceptional* circomstance).  Consider using `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: @Flydog57 when i change it to TryParse i get another saying: the type arguments for method Array.Convertall cannot be inferred from the usage when i hover on ConvertAll

Comment: @FDjawid, Please check my updated answer. I gave solution to use `TryParse` with `Array.ConvertAll()` function

Answer (score 1):

[`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1) returns string instead of list of integer. You need to convert this string into List and pass it to `Consecutive(List<int>)` fucntion

```
...
var input = Console.ReadLine();
//Additional line to convert string to List<string>
var processedInput = Array.ConvertAll(input.Split('-'), int.Parse).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(Consecutive(input));

...
```

---

Explanation of conversion of string to `List<int>`:

- First we are splitting input string by `-` as a delimiter. [`Array.ConvertAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netcore-3.1) converts `IEnumerable<string>` to int. `.ToList()` convert array of integers to `List<int>`.

---

If you want to use `TryParse` to parse integer, then you can use **[out variable feature of C#7.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables)**

```
//This feature is available from C#7. 
//Here if input string fails to parse string to int, it will store 0  as default.
var processedInput = Array.ConvertAll(
          input.Split('-'), x => int.TryParse(x, out var i) ? i : 0)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert String to List,

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var inputs = input.Split("-").Select(int.Parse).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(Consecutive(inputs));
```